# Remove class from previous element ONLY

Tags: javascript

What I would like to do:

1. I want to click on a div which will then have the class "hide-me" added to it upon click. This effectively hides the div.
2. These divs are all stacked up one after the other (think of Tinder where you see one profile after one profile card)
3. I want to be able to click on a button ("undo") which will bring back just **the last div that I just previously clicked**.

My concern is about the javascript part!

Here's what I've done:

```
  HTMLElement.prototype.addClass = function(string) {
  if (!(string instanceof Array)) {
    string = string.split(' ');
  }
  for(var i = 0, len = string.length; i < len; ++i) {
    if (string[i] && !new RegExp('(\\s+|^)' + string[i] + '(\\s+|$)').test(this.className)) {
      this.className = this.className.trim() + ' ' + string[i];
    }}}

HTMLElement.prototype.toggleClass = function(string) {
  if (string) {
    if (new RegExp('(\\s+|^)' + string + '(\\s+|$)').test(this.className)) {
      this.className = this.className.replace(new RegExp('(\\s+|^)' + string + '(\\s+|$)'), ' ').trim();
    } else {
      this.className = this.className.trim() + ' ' + string;
    }}}

    HTMLElement.prototype.removeClass = function(string) {
      if (!(string instanceof Array)) {
        string = string.split(' ');
      }

      for(var i = 0, len = string.length; i < len; ++i) {
        this.className = this.className.replace(new RegExp('(\\s+|^)' + string[i] + '(\\s+|$)'), ' ').trim();
      }}

var hideMe = function(){
    document.getElementById("card").toggleClass("hide-me");} 

var undo = function(){
document.getElementById("card").removeClass("hide-me");}
```

EDIT: give me a moment, i accidentally clicked 'submit' too early.

Comment: How do you have multiple div's with `card` as its id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, sounds like you just need to add a class to the last clicked element and remove existing one

```
var hideMe = function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("last-clicked").removeClass("last-clicked");
    document.getElementById("card").addClass("last-clicked");
    document.getElementById("card").toggleClass("hide-me");} 

var undo = function(){
document.getElementsByClassName("last-clicked").removeClass("hide-me");}
```

Comment: This seems to be the easiest solution so I'm going to implement this!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do something like the example below. You can keep an array stack of hidden divs, and the undo function will un-hide the last item in the array.

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.addClass = function(string) {
  if (!(string instanceof Array)) {
    string = string.split(' ');
  }
  for(var i = 0, len = string.length; i < len; ++i) {
    if (string[i] && !new RegExp('(\\s+|^)' + string[i] + '(\\s+|$)').test(this.className)) {
      this.className = this.className.trim() + ' ' + string[i];
    }}}

HTMLElement.prototype.toggleClass = function(string) {
  if (string) {
    if (new RegExp('(\\s+|^)' + string + '(\\s+|$)').test(this.className)) {
      this.className = this.className.replace(new RegExp('(\\s+|^)' + string + '(\\s+|$)'), ' ').trim();
    } else {
      this.className = this.className.trim() + ' ' + string;
    }}}

    HTMLElement.prototype.removeClass = function(string) {
      if (!(string instanceof Array)) {
        string = string.split(' ');
      }

      for(var i = 0, len = string.length; i < len; ++i) {
        this.className = this.className.replace(new RegExp('(\\s+|^)' + string[i] + '(\\s+|$)'), ' ').trim();
      }}

var undoButton = document.getElementById('undo');
var hiddenStack = [];
var hideMe = function(elem){
    undoButton.removeClass("hide-me");
    elem.parentNode.toggleClass("hide-me");
    hiddenStack.push(elem.parentNode);
} 

var undo = function(){
  var elem = hiddenStack.pop() || null;
  if(elem)
    elem.removeClass("hide-me");
  if(!hiddenStack.length)
    undoButton.addClass('hide-me');
}
```

```css
.hide-me {
    display: none; 
 }
```

```html
<button id="undo" class="hide-me" onclick="undo()">Undo</button>
<div>Profile 1 <button onclick="hideMe(this)">Hide</button></div>
<div>Profile 2 <button onclick="hideMe(this)">Hide</button></div>
<div>Profile 3 <button onclick="hideMe(this)">Hide</button></div>
<div>Profile 4 <button onclick="hideMe(this)">Hide</button></div>
<div>Profile 5 <button onclick="hideMe(this)">Hide</button></div>
```

Comment: That's a really interesting solution. I tried it out earlier, it did work, so thanks so much!!

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's more than you asked for if you're only planning to undo one item at a time.